# Adding UIView to window is not showing in ios8

Tags: ios

I've been working for 1 day on it no solution.I am added uiview to window as subview but it's not showing on top of all viewcontrollers in ios 8

```
UIView *topBarView = [[UIView alloc] init];
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.window addSubview:topBarView];
```

It's working in ios 7 and ios 6 perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you should change.

1. Use `initWithFrame` instead of `init` for `UIView`s.  Give your view a non-zero frame so that it actually takes up space.  Or set its autosizing mask.  Or give it some layout constraints.
2. You should set a `rootViewController` for your `UIWindow` and then add your view as a subview of `window.rootViewController.view`.

Comment: I am tried with your suggestion but its not working.I am setting a rootviewcontroller in appdelegate and setting a frame of view. My requirement is whenever presenting another viewController on rootviewcontroller my subview is visible on top.

Comment: Perhaps you want `self.navigationController.topViewController`?  At this point we're just guessing.  You may need to show more code.